# LINQ To SQL: Parent-Child Relationships Across Multiple DBML Files

Tags: linq-to-sql

In our app, we have a DBML file for each schema in our database. There doesn't appear to be a way to establish a parent-child relationship when the parent table is in one DBML and the child table is in another DBML. At least not without writing some custom code. How is this generally done?

Thanks - Randy